# Weight change when a person on a weight scale swings an object on a string in a vertical circle

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

[image]
Someone is on the scale. Let's say the mass of that person is M. The man is holding an object hanging from a thread. Suppose the weight of an object is m, the length of the thread is r, and the mass of the thread is not present.

Now rotate the object in a direction perpendicular(vertical rotation) to surface, at a constant angular velocity.

In this situation, will the value on the scale change?

I don't want to know how the specific value appears. I asked a friend and he said the value of the scale would not change. I simply cannot accept that, so I post a question.
Does the value of the scale change as the object rotates or does not change?

Comment: It's not clear what is the situation of that object. It is both hanging from the thread and held by the person. Is the tension in the thread equal to the weight, less than the weight or zero?

Comment: The person is holding the thread attached to the object with his hand. When an object is stationary, its tension is equal to its weight. However, the object is not stationary. The tension acting on the object will vary as the object rotates because it is moving in a constant velocity circle in a vertical direction. @nasu

Comment: The scale must also rotate ? All system is rotating

Comment: This question **needs** a diagram. I do not get the geometry even with the clarifying comment. Also, the clarifications should go into the question itself, not just the comments.

Comment: @Dale  Diagram has been inserted into the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My intuition tells me that the key player here is a centrifugal force. In the upper circle point it "lifts-up" a bit person, hence lowering  total weight, in the lower point,- it pushes person a bit to the ground, so normal force from weighting machine support must increase. In general, person spins additional mass $m$ body in a circle, so we can use parametric circle equation to predict total weight effect on scales, which should be :
$$ W = Mg + m\omega^2~r \sin (\varphi +\omega t)  \tag 1$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. It's perfectly understood.

Answer (score 0):

The balance will oscillate with the frequency of the mass. At the uppermost part of the circle m needs a centripetal force down  on the lower most spot up.

Comment: Since the change in measured weight is related to the tension and direction of the string, it might be worth including some reference to the [many relevant Physics SE questions](https://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=vertical+circular+motion+tension).